# intel sgx enabled in bios but in ubuntu system the isgx driver keeps saying "cpu does not support SGX1 instructions"

Tags: drivers, uefi, intel, intel-cpu, sgx

I have a gigabyte b365m motherboard with the newest bios F3a and core i5-9600k. I have set intel sgx to "enabled" in bios but in ubuntu the isgx driver keep saying `intel_sgx: CPU does not support SGX1 instructions` in `dmesg` outputs. And i use the intel's sgx software enable application https://github.com/intel/sgx-software-enable to get the status of SGX. While it says

```
Intel SGX is explicitly disabled, and your BIOS does not
support the "software enable" option. Check your BIOS for an
explicit option to enable Intel SGX.
```

That's so weird!
Then i set the SGX to "software controlled" in bios and in operating system the isgx driver says
`intel_sgx: SGX is not enabled` . I use the SGX software enable application to enable SGX and it says succeeed. But when i reboot my computer and come into the operating system, the weird thing happens again: isgx says `intel_sgx: CPU does not support SGX1 instructions`. But the output of SGX enable application becomes:

```
The software enable has been performed on this system and
Intel SGX will be enabled after the system is rebooted.
```

Then i rebooted again but things didn't change. isgx driver still says:

```
intel_sgx: CPU does not support SGX1 instructions
```

and the outputs of the SGX application is still

```
The software enable has been performed on this system and
Intel SGX will be enabled after the system is rebooted.
```

Why did things come to this? The website https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html shows obviously that 9600k supports SGX. Can this be an incompatibility problem between ubuntu and bios?
output of `cpuid|grep SGX`:

```
      SGX: Software Guard Extensions supported = true
      SGX_LC: SGX launch config supported      = true
   Software Guard Extensions (SGX) capability (0x12/0):
      SGX1 supported                         = false
      SGX2 supported                         = false
      SGX ENCLV E*VIRTCHILD, ESETCONTEXT     = false
      SGX ENCLS ETRACKC, ERDINFO, ELDBC, ELDUC = false
      SGX: Software Guard Extensions supported = true
      SGX_LC: SGX launch config supported      = true
   Software Guard Extensions (SGX) capability (0x12/0):
      SGX1 supported                         = false
      SGX2 supported                         = false
      SGX ENCLV E*VIRTCHILD, ESETCONTEXT     = false
      SGX ENCLS ETRACKC, ERDINFO, ELDBC, ELDUC = false
      SGX: Software Guard Extensions supported = true
      SGX_LC: SGX launch config supported      = true
   Software Guard Extensions (SGX) capability (0x12/0):
      SGX1 supported                         = false
      SGX2 supported                         = false
      SGX ENCLV E*VIRTCHILD, ESETCONTEXT     = false
      SGX ENCLS ETRACKC, ERDINFO, ELDBC, ELDUC = false
      SGX: Software Guard Extensions supported = true
      SGX_LC: SGX launch config supported      = true
   Software Guard Extensions (SGX) capability (0x12/0):
      SGX1 supported                         = false
      SGX2 supported                         = false
      SGX ENCLV E*VIRTCHILD, ESETCONTEXT     = false
      SGX ENCLS ETRACKC, ERDINFO, ELDBC, ELDUC = false
      SGX: Software Guard Extensions supported = true
      SGX_LC: SGX launch config supported      = true
   Software Guard Extensions (SGX) capability (0x12/0):
      SGX1 supported                         = false
      SGX2 supported                         = false
      SGX ENCLV E*VIRTCHILD, ESETCONTEXT     = false
      SGX ENCLS ETRACKC, ERDINFO, ELDBC, ELDUC = false
      SGX: Software Guard Extensions supported = true
      SGX_LC: SGX launch config supported      = true
   Software Guard Extensions (SGX) capability (0x12/0):
      SGX1 supported                         = false
      SGX2 supported                         = false
      SGX ENCLV E*VIRTCHILD, ESETCONTEXT     = false
      SGX ENCLS ETRACKC, ERDINFO, ELDBC, ELDUC = false
```

output of `dmidecode -t bios`:

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
        Version: F3a
        Release Date: 11/28/2019
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 16 MB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                BIOS ROM is socketed
                EDD is supported
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 5.12

Handle 0x0043, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
        Language Description Format: Long
        Installable Languages: 15
                en|US|iso8859-1
                zh|TW|unicode
                zh|CN|unicode
                ru|RU|iso8859-5
                de|DE|iso8859-1
                ja|JP|unicode
                ko|KR|unicode
                es|ES|iso8859-1
                fr|FR|iso8859-1
                it|IT|iso8859-1
                pt|PT|iso8859-1
                vi|VI|iso8859-1
                id|ID|iso8859-1
                tr|TR|iso8859-1
                pl|PL|iso8859-1
        Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks! :-)